# In Blender 2.83, what happened to Overlay Blend-type in Grease Pencil?

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d

I recently upgraded from Blender 2.81a to 2.83.0. In 2.81, Overlay was a Blend-mode option in Grease Pencil (and I often used it to add specular highlights in 2D work):

[image]

In 2.83.0, Overlay appears to be have disappeared, though Hard Light is now a new option:

[image]

Based on https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-layer-modes.html, Overlay and Hard Light appears to be distinct blend modes, and I am not yet sure if it is a suitable replacement in my workflow.

Was Overlay in fact removed from Grease Pencil Blend-modes (or am I missing a some way to access it), and, if so, are there any good alternatives to it?